# How to remove rel=publisher tag in blogger?

Tags: templates, blogger, blogspot, structured-data

I have searched for this a hundred times and only found how to add such tags in Blogger. I have not found a tutorial on how to remove those tags if they are added automatically by Blogger / Blogspot.

In my head area of one of my Blogspot blogs using a custom domain, the tag is added automatically as:

```
<link href='MY_GOOGLE_PLUS_URL' rel='publisher'/>
```

I try to remove it, but I cannot find the code anywhere in the template. I used the same template code (copy/pasted xml) in some other blog created by the same Google account. The code does not show there.

I have one more custom domain hosted at Blogger but it does not show the publisher tag automatically.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After a day of messing around I'm answering my own question.**

Turns out if we create a blogger blog (with a custom domain in my case) and add that blogger blog to the list of contributed blog in our Google Plus, rel=publisher of that Google Plus id is automatically added. Once I removed the link from my Google Plus, the code in the header:

```
<link href='MY_GOOGLE_PLUS_URL' rel='publisher'/>
```

Dissappears !!

Answer (score 0):

just delete

```
<span class='meta_autor'>
Publisher: <a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl'> 
<data:post.author/>
  </a><span class='meta_date'> - <data:post.timestamp/></span></span>
```

Comment: You may want to add clarification why the deletion is necessary to further help Ashish.

Answer (score 0):

In your template search for

`<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>`

code. After finding this code remove it then save. Now check your `rel="publisher"` 
tag gone from your theme.